# How to make a 2D scatter plot colored by the value of a third parameter

Tags: plotting, legending

As the title suggests I'm trying to make a 2D (x-y) scatter plot of the list {x,y,z}, colored by the value of a third parameter (z). I came the closest by using `ListPointPlot3D`, but unfortunately that gives a 3D box plot whereas I want to get something like this

[image]

without the contour lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Any ideas for a legend regarding the "colors - z values" would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Does `ListPlot[Style[{#1, #2}, Hue[#3]] & @@@ data]` work for you? it's a bit hard to tell without code (or without knowing how you want to convert the `z` value into color)

Comment: Please post your code.Maybe `DensityPlot`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no dedicated built-in function for this task, which I find rather strange given how often this is needed. (Unless something that I am not aware of was added recently.) Therefore, I usually implement this from scratch.

Let us generate some example data:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 3}];
```

There actually *is* a similar function, but it is designed for small datasets: [`BubbleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html). We can turn off the bubble sizing to get what you want:

```
BubbleChart[data, BubbleSizes -> .1 {1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

If you have large data, you can do something like this:

```
(* Choose a colour function: *)
cf = ColorData["Rainbow"]
```

```
Graphics[{
  PointSize[0.03], 
  Point[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], VertexColors -> cf /@ Rescale[data[[All, 3]]]]
}]
```

This is a very fast rendering solution because I used a *single* [`Point`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html) primitive instead of separate ones for each point. It takes maybe 1-2 seconds for ~100,000 points, and it can handle a million if you are patient and [`Rasterize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) the output (although at that point it makes sense to start histogramming the data).

If for some reason I need separate styling for each point (e.g. to control sizes as well) or I need to use `Disk[]` instead of `Point[]` to prioritize quality over performance, I do something like the following:

```
Graphics[
 MapThread[
   {cf[#2], Disk[#1, 0.03]} &, 
   {data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], Rescale[data[[All, 3]]]}]
 ]
```

---

As for the legend, you also need to do it manually. For example:

```
mima = MinMax[data[[All, 3]]];
BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", mima}], mima}]
```

Comment: This works excellent and fast, do you know if it's possible to add the x-y axis as well, to make it look like a complete plot?

Comment: @CoolCookie Look up the options available for `Graphics`. You can use `Axes -> True` or `Frame -> True`, whichever you prefer. There are many other options to customize this.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

In versions 12.2+, you can use [`PointValuePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointValuePlot.html) which allows multiple parameters that can be associated with color/size/shape/... of 2D points:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {8, 6}];

PointValuePlot[data[[All, ;; 2]] -> 
     MapAt[ToString[Round[#, .1]] &, data[[All, 3 ;;]], {All, {1, -1}}], 
 {2 -> "Color", 3 -> "Size", 4 -> "Shape"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]